# Tezos for Python

Tags: smart-contracts, python

I am quite new to Python, using it for about half a year. I want to learn coding on Tezos blockchain and got some questions for you.

1. Is there a chance to deploy smart contract using python? I know Pytezos and SmartPy, but didnt see if it allow yo deploy smart contract.
2. Is there any other ways to send XTZ using python?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

PyTezos and SmartPy allow you to write smart contracts in Python, which is then transpiled into Michelson (the native language of Tezos). You then need to use the `tezos-client` to deploy this Michelson code and generate your contract address.

Comment: Both SmartPy (editor and CLI) and Pytezos provide a good support for deployment.

Comment: I haven't see either used to deploy. The last tutorial I read showed using the CLI which is why I answered as such.

Comment: Sure, no bad feelings at all!

Answer (score 1):

There is also PyMich: *Write Pure Python and get Micheline Code with PyMich: Open Source Python to Tezos Micheline Smart Contract Source Code Transpiler.*
https://yourlabs.io/pyratzlabs/pymich

And a great tool to deploy and test contracts is Chinstrap - you can work there with Smartpy or PyTezos.
https://docs.chinstrap.io/